# Debezium with SQL server certificate

Tags: debezium

my connector complain about certificate RSA keysize when I try to connect SQL Server

`Algorithm constraints check failed on keysize limits: RSA 1024 bit key used with certificate`

It is strange that we tried couple servers with the same setup but only one got this error.

I have tried 1.6.3 and 1.9.5 both of them have the same error on certain servers.

I know it is set from java.security but it still doesn't work if I make the change like removing `RSA keysize < 2048`

Another question is why it only happens to certain server. As far as I know, all my servers use 1024 bit RSA for certificate and encrypt is not enabled for the connection either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently there is another config located at /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config

So here is what I end up doing

```
ARG STRIMZI_VERSION="0.28.0"
ARG KAFKA_VERSION="3.1.0"
ARG DEBEZIUM_VERSION="1.9.5.Final"

FROM quay.io/debezium/connect:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION} as connectors
FROM quay.io/strimzi/kafka:${STRIMZI_VERSION}-kafka-${KAFKA_VERSION}

USER root:root
ARG DEBEZIUM_CONNECTOR="sqlserver"
COPY --from=connectors /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-${DEBEZIUM_CONNECTOR}/ /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-${DEBEZIUM_CONNECTOR}/
RUN sed -i -e 's/RSA keySize < 2048,//g' /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.14.0.9-2.el8_5.x86_64/conf/security/java.security \
    & sed -i -e 's/, RSA keySize < 2048//g' /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config

USER 1001
```

Although it would be nice if someone can answer why debezium would check keysize on certain server only.